# Select a specific object from a queryset django

Tags: python, django

Is there any way to select a specific object that is found in the results of a queryset like selecting an item in an array.

In arrays, you can select a specific item based on its position:

```
arrayName = {55, 33, 34, 23}
arrayName[2]
result = 34
```

I want to accomplish the same thing with queryset results

```
Users in database = {Steve, Chris, Jame, Cole, Casper, Courtney}
Query will filter the names that start with c
result = {Chris, COle, Casper, Courtney}
```

After I get the results, I want to select Casper from the results...
is there a way to do it like an array.

```
something like results[2]
```

**UPDATE**

So I have the part of the view working that will specify a specific record.

My only other question is to see if it is possible to do the same thing in the HTML tempalte file... Here is what I have in the view and html file. is there a way to do the same thing ht ehtml file...

view.py

```
                i=0
                    for form in formset:
                        cd = form.cleaned_data
                        currentAmount = cd['amount']
                        currentDescription = cd['description']
                        print(currentAmount)
                        print(currentDescription)
                        currentTrans = transactions[i]
                        currentTrans.amount = currentAmount
                        currentTrans.description = currentDescription
                        currentTrans.save()
                        print(currentTrans)
                        i = i + 1
```

html

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ SplitFormSet.management_form }}
    {% for form in SplitFormSet %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
    {% endfor %}
    <p>Tax: <input type="text" name="tax" value=""></p>
    <p>Tip: <input type="text" name="tip" value=""></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

I tried this but it game me an error becuase 'i' is not a tag

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ SplitFormSet.management_form }}
    {% i = 0 %}
    {% for form in SplitFormSet %}
      {{ transactions[i] }}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      {% i = i + 1 %}
    {% endfor %}
    <p>Tax: <input type="text" name="tax" value=""></p>
    <p>Tip: <input type="text" name="tip" value=""></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: Why dont you try that code and see if that works or not ?

Comment: In Python, `{55, 33, 34, 23}` is a **set**, not a list. In the example you have given, `arrayName[2]` will raise a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names=Model.objects.filter(name__istartswith='c')

print(names[2])
```

In place of name you have put the field name of you model

Comment: I have no idea why that was not working previously. i tried it and it worked this time...

Comment: bro can you upvote the answer as you have the privilege, thanks @OmarJandali

Comment: I worked perfectly, but i have another question if you can check it.. it is going to be in the update part of my post..  @Exprator